# How to proxy password protected proxy by using nginx? Proxy_set_header Authorization does not work

Tags: proxy, nginx

I have a LAN proxy and I want to forward it to a server using Nginx. Here is my configuration:

```
stream {
    upstream e_proxy {
    server 192.168.23.23:10000;
}

server {  
    listen 10000;  
    proxy_pass e_proxy;  
    proxy_protocol on;  
    # proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic xxxxxxxx"; <-- error
}
```

This configuration works well with a standard proxy. However, if the server at `192.168.23.23:10000` requires a username and password authentication, the configuration won't work. Adding the `proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic xxxxxxxx";` statement produces an immediate `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_set_header" directive is not allowed here` error.

How to make Nginx support forward an authorized proxy?